# Magento 1.9.1 model extend not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add new method Mage_Eav_Model_Form, so I want to extend it. Doing as it suppose to be, but extension simply not working. Here is my part from config:

```
<models>
<vendor_mymodule>
    <class>Vendor_Mymodule_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>tw_subscriptionheader_resource</resourceModel>
</vendor_mymodule>
<vendor_mymodule_resource>
    <class>Vendor_Mymodule_Model_Resource</class>
</vendor_mymodule_resource>
<eav>
    <rewrite>
        <form>Venor_Mymodule_Model_Eav_Form</form>
    </rewrite>
</eav>
```

Here is original model:

```
abstract class Mage_Eav_Model_Form
```

And mine:

```
class Vendor_Mymodule_Model_Eav_Form extends Mage_Eav_Model_Form
```

For example I want to add:

```
public function something() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite is not correct, plus you should put the 'core' folder with the 'Model' folder

In config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <domainpolicy>Me_Mymodule_Model_Core_Domainpolicy</domainpolicy>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
```

Path

```
 app/code/local/Me/Mymodule/Model/Core/Domainpolicy.php
```

Class

```
 class Me_Mymodule_Model_Core_Domainpolicy extends Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy
```